# Get the line number in Edit control

Tags: winapi, editcontrol

how can you get the current line number in a multi-line edit control?

Comment: Doesn't really matter - he said "winapi" in his tags. While it would be easier to do in C#... :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the docs for `EM_LINEFROMCHAR`, if you pass `-1` as `wParam`, you get the line number of the line containing the caret (or the start of the selection if there is one).

Answer (score 2):

Look at the `EM_LINEFROMCHAR` window message.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try checking the MSDN index for anything beginning with EM_*. If you did, you'd find EM_LINEFROMCHAR, EM_LINEINDEX, EM_LINELENGTH, etc, which can probably solve your problem